# apps script google sheets api to create a Relative Reference in Drop-Down Menu in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Relative references for dropdown's is a technique to allow for dynamic content in the dropdown.  There are several articles on how to create dynamic dropdown's using relative references such as this one: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/relative-reference-in-drop-down-google-sheets/.

I am trying to create dynamic dropdowns using relative references using apps script api calls.  The problem that I am facing is that there doesn't appear to be an API call available to set the data validation (drop down from range) without the use of an actual range.  The current api calls that I am using call for selecting the range, then calling build.  Here is some sudo-code for the current method and problem.

Say I wanted to dynamically load data into the dropdown based on the values found in B1:K for a dropdown in each row of column A.   Manually I could achieve this by setting up data validation for column A, and recording "=B1:K" in the range selector of the (drop down from range) data validation builder.   The result would be that each row in column A, would have a dropdown whose content comes from the corresponding row Bx:Kx.

To setup data validation via apps script, I need to run the following code:

```
function qtest(){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    var dropdownRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,10);
    var selectorRange=spreadsheet.getRangeByName("B1:K");
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(selectorRange).build();
   dropdownRange.setDataValidation(criteria);
}
```

This will result in an absolute reference of =sheet!$B$1:$K for the data validation.

Using this function methodology, you cannot set an arbitrary string for the dropdown like you can manually.  We would need to set "=B1:K", with the "=" sign being the key flag in setting up the relative reference.  Because the current API's requireValueInRange 1) requires an absolute range, 2) fixes to an abosolute range, I cannot figure out a way to programmatically set a relative range.

Are you aware of another technique, or does google need to create a a new method such as

'requireValueInRelativeRange(string)'

for reference, here are the current avaiable APIs https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And, you don't want to use Google Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) and you want to use only Sheets API. Is my understanding correct? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.